# How to modify the framework to support muti-skin?

Tags: android

How to modify the frmework to support muti-skin? The effect is like HTC desire HD which can change the skin dynamically. The skin is from a separate apk. Who can give me some precious advice? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking out how OpenIntents does it. The app OI Notepad on the market supports multiple themes. It's an open source project, so you can [read the source](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/#svn/trunk/notepad/NotePad) and see how they did it.